# merging 2d arrays to get 3d array in c

Tags: c

I have 5 1D arrays .I want to merge them into a single 5*5 array(2 D array). How do we do that?(using C)

what I tried:

```
int arr[5][5] = {*arr1,*arr2,*arr3,*arr4,*arr5};
```

why doesn't this work?

Comment: The reason is - You are using * i.e. pointers... Each array's pointer is nothing but a memory location... *arr1 is one "long", *arr2 is one "long" and so on...

Comment: Please update your title to reflect the question.

Answer (score 2):

I solve it same as that:

```
void setArr (int i, int arr[5][5], int arri[5])
{
  int j;
  for (j=0;j<5;j++)
  {
     arr[i][j] = arri[j];
  }
}
```

// in main function

```
int main ()
{
 ... 
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     switch (i)
      case 0: setArr(i,arr,arr1);
          break;
      case 1: setArr(i,arr,arr2);
          break;
      case 2: setArr(i,arr,arr3);
          break;
      case 3: setArr(i,arr,arr4);
          break;
      default: setArr(i,arr,arr5);
          break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. The first is that arrays decays to pointers, so when you do `*arr1` you get the value that the *pointer* `arr1` points to, which is the first element in the array `arr1`.

The second problem is that since arrays decays to pointer, you need to make an array of pointers.

So you should do e.g.

```
int *arr[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5 };
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because

```
int *arr;
```

is not equivalent to

```
int arr[5];
```

In the first case you're declaring just a pointer, in the second you declare a pointer AND allocate memory.